# Element wise prop.test in R

Tags: r

I'm trying to create a function that does an element wise prop.test in R between the x1 and x2 variables and returns a list of p-values for each test. x1 and x2 represent the number of success in each category. I was thinking that sapply would do the trick but I cannot figure out how to get it to work.

```
set.seed(4576)

x1 <- round(runif(15, 200, 1000))
x2 <- round(runif(15, 200, 1000))

p <- cbind(x1, x2)

       x1  x2
 [1,] 919 559
 [2,] 471 975
 [3,] 537 792
 [4,] 776 524
 [5,] 329 603
 [6,] 201 610
 [7,] 520 353
 [8,] 461 853
 [9,] 491 765
[10,] 527 358
[11,] 248 331
[12,] 953 322
[13,] 453 680
[14,] 401 654
[15,] 962 358

function(data) {

    n1 <- sum(data[,1])
    n2 <- sum(data[,2])

    sapply(data, function(x) {

    prop.test(x = c(data[,1], data[,2]), n = c(n1, n2) )$p.value   

    } )

}
```

I'm probably just misunderstanding how to use sapply but any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably easiest to `sapply` to the row indices, then you don't have to extract every value from `p` manually.

```
sapply(1:nrow(p), function(z) prop.test(p[z,, drop = FALSE])$p.value)
#  [1] 9.810393e-21 6.072933e-40 3.228340e-12 3.366985e-12 3.807659e-19 1.487836e-46 1.929026e-08 3.988440e-27 1.327621e-14 1.630269e-08 6.548799e-04
# [12] 1.141069e-69 1.891166e-11 8.598155e-15 7.322714e-62
```

It is not exactly clear what your data represent, but I'm assuming in the above that the two columns in `p` are counts of successes and failures, respectively.

This matters because R will actually execute a different proportion test depending on exactly what data structure you supply. Example:

```
> sapply(1:nrow(p), function(z) prop.test(p[z,, drop = FALSE], n = colSums(p))$p.value)
 [1] 9.810393e-21 6.072933e-40 3.228340e-12 3.366985e-12 3.807659e-19 1.487836e-46 1.929026e-08 3.988440e-27 1.327621e-14 1.630269e-08 6.548799e-04 1.141069e-69
[13] 1.891166e-11 8.598155e-15 7.322714e-62
> sapply(1:nrow(p), function(z) prop.test(p[z,, drop = TRUE], n = colSums(p))$p.value)
 [1] 7.981801e-28 6.509059e-37 6.883520e-10 8.391497e-17 1.044857e-16 1.291989e-43 3.079194e-11 3.329273e-24 3.663355e-12 2.373325e-11 5.689494e-03 5.212655e-84
[13] 2.658030e-09 1.781938e-12 2.023293e-75
```

These numbers are all floating point representations of 0, so the different in this case is irrelevant, but if you take a look at a single iteration of these two different types of codes you'll see what R is doing different and thus why it is giving you different p-values:

```
> prop.test(p[1,, drop = FALSE], n = colSums(p))

        1-sample proportions test with continuity correction

data:  p[1, , drop = FALSE], null probability 0.5
X-squared = 87.1996, df = 1, p-value < 2.2e-16
alternative hypothesis: true p is not equal to 0.5
95 percent confidence interval:
 0.5964359 0.6464965
sample estimates:
        p 
0.6217862 

> prop.test(p[1,, drop = TRUE], n = colSums(p))

        2-sample test for equality of proportions with continuity correction

data:  p[1, , drop = TRUE] out of colSums(p)
X-squared = 119.5388, df = 1, p-value < 2.2e-16
alternative hypothesis: two.sided
95 percent confidence interval:
 0.03879812 0.05605522
sample estimates:
    prop 1     prop 2 
0.11140744 0.06398077
```

Supplying the `n` argument actually doesn't matter if `drop = FALSE` (i.e., if you supply a matrix) because the test it is performing is a comparison of the two numbers in the row.

It sounds like that is not what you want, so you should specify `drop = TRUE` (which is the default, and thus you don't actually have to supply it) but specify `n`, as I do in the second set of code above.

Comment: Oh really interesting so in p[z,, drop = FALSE] the z equals the indices and the two commas indicate where the row and columns would go normally go. What does the drop = FALSE do?

Comment: @moku Exactly. `drop = FALSE` prevents R from converting the extracted row of the matrix into a vector. The default (`drop = TRUE`) would give you a two-element numeric vector instead of a 1x2 numeric matrix.

Comment: When I test the first value:                                                                prop.test(x = c(919, 559), n = c(sum(p[,1]), sum(p[,2]) ))$p.value = 7.981801e-28 that different than 9.810393e-21

Comment: Guess I should say that x1 and x2 represent the number of success in each category

Comment: `mapply(function(x,y) prop.test(as.table(c(x,y)))$p.value, p[,1], p[,2])` for an `mapply` variation on this answer.

Comment: These answers seem incorrect. In the first iteration the prop test should be comparing 919/8249 vs 559/8737 which returns a p-value of 7.981801e-28  not 9.810393e-21

Comment: @moku Where are you getting "8249" and "8737" from? Also, all of those p-values are 0 even if their display values differ.

Comment: Sum(p[,1]) = 8249   Sum(p[,2]) = 8737 imagine that the p dataframe is a large crosstab where each row represents a different category for one question and each column is a category for one question